# Ansible how to sort output of command from multiple nodes

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible playbook that runs some command on all my nodes to generate a list of
available images. Then on my ansible controller, I want to generate a combined, sorted
list with all duplicates removed.
I have a playbook:

```
- hosts: kube_cluster
  tasks:
  - command: crictl images
    become: yes
    register: cri_images

  - name: save results
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: yes
    become: no
    copy:
      dest: cri_images.txt
      content: |
            {% for h in ansible_play_hosts %}
              {{ hostvars[h].cri_images.stdout  }}
            {% endfor %}
```

that does generate the file, but I fail to get the sorting of the combined output.

I would get, for each of the nodes, output like:

```
docker.io/bitnami/contour                          1.17.1-debian-10-r0    5be5c048ac5e2       132MB
docker.io/bitnami/envoy                            1.17.3-debian-10-r62   7ff8d931d11c7       150MB
docker.io/calico/cni                               v3.19.1                5749e8b276f9b       146MB
docker.io/calico/node                              v3.19.1                c4d75af7e098e       171MB
```

available in the 'stdout_lines'. Some lines are duplicated across some of the nodes.

I fail to adapt the jinja code to sort, and remove duplicates. Probably need some form of nested loop, or a means to flatten the the `hostvars[h].cri_images.stdout`.
But I could not figure out how to do that. Most I got were syntax/template errors.

As an extra, I'd also like to:

- remove the header line of the output
- have the option to select only few of the columns of the combined output.

In a shell script this could be achieved easily by a

`cat cri_images.txt | grep -v ^IMAGES | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}' | sort | uniq`

but requirement is that it would have to run in Ansible.

anyone have a hint?
thx.

Comment: `I fail to get the sorting of the combined output.` ... `remove the header line of the output` ... `select only few of the columns of the combined output` <= what do you get and what do you expect exactly? What does your input data look like? Please edit your question.

Comment: I would get, for each of the nodes output like:
```ok: [master1] => {
    "msg": [
        "IMAGE                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE", 
        "docker.io/calico/cni                  v3.19.1             5749e8b276f9b       146MB", 
...
        "k8s.gcr.io/pause                      3.5                 ed210e3e4a5ba       686kB"
    ]
```

but then in the 'stdout_lines'. Trying selection through the original code, all I got were syntax/template errors. But using answer of @Vladimir Botka I was able to to the sort and uni.

Comment: comments are not made for large pieces of code or output nor to add information needed to correctly answer your question. This is why my last sentence was: `Please edit your question`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: *"**Some command on all my nodes to generate a list of available images ...  generate a combined, sorted list with all duplicates removed.**"*

A: For testing, let's split the hostnames, instead of generating the lists of available images, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        cri_images: "{{ {}|combine({'stdout_lines': 
                                    inventory_hostname.split('_')}) }}"
    - debug:
        var: cri_images.stdout_lines
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_12] => 
  cri_images.stdout_lines:
  - test
  - '12'
ok: [test_11] => 
  cri_images.stdout_lines:
  - test
  - '11'
ok: [test_13] => 
  cri_images.stdout_lines:
  - test
  - '13'
```

Then, generate a combined, sorted list with all duplicates removed

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: cri_images.txt
        content: "{{ _content | join('\n') }}"
      vars:
        _content: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                      map('extract', hostvars, ['cri_images', 'stdout_lines'])|
                      flatten|unique|sort }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat cri_images.txt
11
12
13
test
```

Comment: great @Vladimir ! Basically the only thing I had to modify is adding a `join('\n')` in the write to the file. This solves the basic challenge. I was able to do the column selection already in the initial command (yeah, with awk), although I would prefer to do that in Ansible also.